# angularjs: force to use array value is select

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ng-options

I'm relatively new to AngularJS, so maybe my question is stupid, but I cannot find an answer.

I have prepared example to explain my problem, it can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DGn6mAKeitcMg9jnKxP2?p=preview).
When controller instantiates it has some values passed from parent scope. In my example:

```
$scope.modelId = 2;
$scope.sizeA = 2;   // this is initial values 
$scope.sizeB = 180; //   for select elements
```

Then controller requests from server other values for the lists. It loads:

```
"sizesA": [1, 2, 6, 9, 10],
"sizesB": [120, 180, 300]
```

After data is loaded, we can see initialized `select`s on page:

```
SizeA: <select ng-model="sizeA" ng-options="s for s in model.sizesA"></select>
SizeB: <select ng-model="sizeB" ng-options="s for s in model.sizesB"></select>
```

`sizeB` is initialized to value 180 (as expected), but `sizeA` is initialized to value 6 (with index 2) instead of value 2.

When I specify `$scope.sizeA = 9;` in controller (there is no index 9, but there such value) it selects item with value 9.

So the question: how can I tell angular to use value

Comment: Please provide a plnkr (http://plnkr.co/)

Comment: There link into second paragraph (on word "here"). P.S. http://plnkr.co/edit/DGn6mAKeitcMg9jnKxP2?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `track by`:

```
<select ng-model="sizeA" 
        ng-options="size for size in model.sizesA track by size"></select>
```